# Taking stalk of a product of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(\mathscr{F}_\alpha)_\alpha$ be a family of sheaves on $X$, and $\prod_\alpha\mathscr{F}_\alpha$ the product sheaf. If $x\in X$, is it true that
$$\left(\prod_\alpha\mathscr{F}_\alpha\right)_x\simeq\prod_\alpha(\mathscr{F}_\alpha)_x \ ?$$
I think $(\oplus_\alpha\mathscr{F}_\alpha)_x\simeq\oplus_\alpha(\mathscr{F}_\alpha)_x$ may be true, but not the product sheaf.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right. It is true for direct sums, even arbitrary colimits (since colimits commute with colimits, and remember the description of the stalk as a colimit; or represent it as a pullback functor to the point), and also for *finite* products, even more generally for finite limits (since these commute with *filtered* colimits in, say, algebraic categories, in which the sheaves should live). But it is not true for infinite products.

There is always a canonical map $(\prod_{\alpha} F_{\alpha})_x \to \prod_{\alpha} (F_{\alpha})_x$. But it doesn't have to be injective, even for very nice spaces $X$ and sheaves $F_{\alpha}$. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $F_{\alpha}$ the sheaf of continuous function for $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, and $x=0$. Let $f_{\alpha} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which vanishes on $]-1/(\alpha+1),+1/(\alpha+1)[$, but does not vanish at $1/{\alpha}$. Then $(f_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ represents an element in the kernel of the canonical map, which is not trivial.