# Serre: coherent $\iff$ locally finitely presented, when sheaf coherent over itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

*Note: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963398/coherent-sheaves-vs-sheaves-locally-of-finite-presentation) question is relevant but doesn't answer my question.*

I want to prove the following proposition from (an English translation of) Jean-Pierre Serre's article *Faisceaux algébriques cohérents*. Serre only gives an outline of the proof.

> When $\mathscr A$ is a coherent sheaf of rings, we have the following results:
>
> PROPOSITION 7. For a sheaf of $\mathscr A$-modules, being coherent is equivalent to being locally isomorphic to the cokernel of a homomorphism $\phi : \mathscr A^q \to \mathscr A^p$.

In other words, when $\mathscr A$ is coherent over itself, the implications
$$
    \text{coherent} \iff \text{locally finitely presented}
  $$
hold for any sheaf $\mathscr F$ of $\mathscr A$-modules. I'm unable to prove the $\impliedby$ implication. Serre only gives an outline:

> Proof. The necessity part is Proposition 2; the sufficiency follows from the coherence of $\mathscr A^q$ and $\mathscr A^p$ and from Theorem 2.

From earlier:

> THEOREM 2. Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from a coherent sheaf $\mathscr F$ to a coherent sheaf $\mathscr G$. The kernel, cokernel, and the image of $\phi$ are also coherent sheaves.

---

Serre's definition of a coherent sheaf:

> Definition 2. A sheaf $\mathscr F$ of $\mathscr A$-modules is said to be coherent if:
>
> (a) $\mathscr F$ is of finite type,
>
> (b) If $s_1, \ldots, s_p$ are sections of $\mathscr F$ over an open $U \subset X$, the sheaf of relations between the $s_i$ is of finite type (over the open set $U$).

I believe (b) is equivalent to the following criterion from the [nLab definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+sheaf):

> For every open $U$ in the base space, every finite $p \in \mathbb N$ and every morphism
> $$ \mathscr A^p |_U \to \mathscr F |_U $$
> of $\mathscr O |_U$-modules has a finitely generated kernel.

---

**My attempt**. Suppose $\mathscr A$ is a sheaf on $X$, and coherent over itself. Let $\mathscr F$ be a locally finitely presented $\mathscr A$-module. Then each $x \in X$ is contained in some open $U_x \ni x$ for which a sequence
$$
    \mathscr A^q |_{U_x} \to \mathscr A^p |_{U_x} \to \mathscr F |_{U_x} \to 0
  $$
exists. Since $A^q |_{U_x}$ and $A^p |_{U_x}$ are coherent, so is $\mathscr F |_{U_x}$. $\color{red}{\text{Now what?}}$ The problem is that *every* morphism $\sigma : \mathscr A^s |_V \to \mathscr F |_V$ must have a finitely generated kernel for *any* $s$ and *any* open $V \subseteq X$, not just the $U_x$ from above. Is there some shortcut I'm missing, or is delving into the details of the sheaf of relations necessary? Can it be proven on stalks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what's missing here is the following:

> $\mathscr{F}$ is coherent if and only if $\mathscr{F}|_{U_i}$ are coherent on $U_i$, for an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$.

Let's prove this. One direction is more or less immediate, so we focus on the other. We then have an open cover $\{U_i\}$ on which $\mathscr{F}$ is coherent. The finite type part of coherence is immediate, since the $U_i$ cover $X$ so we only focus on the second one.

Let $V \subset X$ be open and $s_1, \dots, s_p \in \mathscr{F}(V)$. Let $\mathscr{R}$ be the sheaf of relations for these sections. We must show $\mathscr{R}$ is a finite type sheaf on $V$. To do so, observe that $\mathscr{R}|_{V \cap U_i}$ is finite type for each $i$, since $\mathscr{F}|_{U_i}$ is coherent. Indeed, this is the sheaf of relations for $s_1|_{V \cap U_i}, \dots, s_p|_{V \cap Y_i} \in \mathscr{F}(U_i \cap V) = \mathscr{F}|_{U_i}(U_i \cap V)$.

Since the $V \cap U_i$ cover $V$, it follows that $\mathscr{R}$ is finite type on $V$ as required.

Comment: Wonderful. I think mentioning generators might not even be necessary; does the following argument look right? Take arbitrary $\sigma : \mathscr A^s |_V \to \mathscr F |_V$. Then the restricted sheaf kernel $(\ker \sigma) |_{V \cap U_i}$ is finitely generated, since $\mathscr F |_{U_i}$ is coherent. But this holds for all $i \in I$, so $\ker \sigma$ must be finitely generated on all of $V$!

Comment: That sounds right to me! @JeremyLindsay