# When is $Hom(F,G)$ quasicoherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, and $\mathcal{G}$ is quasicoherent, $Hom(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ is quasicoherent. In the standard proof of this, I am not sure where coherence is applied (it seems only necessary that $\mathcal{F}$ is finitely presented). Where is quasicoherence used in the proof of this, or is it only necessary for the sheaf to be finitely presented?

Comment: If the "standard proof" you refer to is the "standard proof" I know, it should be pretty clear where you need quasi-coherence of $\mathcal{G}$. Can you write down the proof you say is standard?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to ask when is it used that $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent rather than just finitely presented.

Comment: By the definition of quasicoherence, it is only necessary to prove that for $A$ modules $M$ and $N$, $Hom(M,N)_f$ is isomorphic to $Hom(M_f, N_f)$. But this is true whenever $M$ is finitely presented.

Comment: Yes, that's true, $\mathcal{F}$ locally of finite presentation is sufficient. This has been addressed before on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984980/stalks-of-the-sheaf-mathscrhom). I propose marking this question as a duplicate of that one - what do you think?